# Fixed navigation wont auto width

Tags: html, css

I have some troubles with fixed navigation. I tried putting `width: 100%;` but since I have margins it overflow them. Then I tried `width: auto;` and it just fit half of my web site. So whats the deal here?

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

p {
  font-family: "Allerta Stencil";
  font-size: 25px;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: -5px;
  width: auto;
}

#navigacija {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #089DE3;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
}

.navitem {
  background: #089DE3;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navigacija a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  float: right;
}

.home:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.info:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #089DE3;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

#p1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HTML i CSS</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jockey+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta+Stencil" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="navigacija">
      <a href="Home.html">
        <div class="navitem home"><b>HOME</b></div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="navitem gallery"><b>GALLERY</b></div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="navitem contact"><b>CONTACT</b></div>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="navitem info"><b>INFO</b></div>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h1><b>HTML i CSS</b></h1>

  <h2>HTML</h2>
  <p><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" alt="html logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;"> HTML (engl. HyperText Markup Language, jezik za oznacavanje hiperteksta) je opisni jezik specijalno namenjen opisu veb stranica.
    Pomocu njega se jednostavno mogu odvojiti elementi kao sto su naslovi, paragrafi, citati i slicno. Pored toga, u HTML standard su ugradjeni elementi koji detaljnije opisuju sam dokument kao sto su kratak opis dokumenta, kljucne reci, podaci o autoru
    i slicno. Ovi podaci su opstepoznati kao meta podaci i jasno su odvojeni od sadrzaja dokumenta. Aktuelna verzija standarda je HTML 4.01, a sam standard odrzava Konzorcijum za Veb (W3C, World Wide Web Consortium).HTML je nastao uproscavanjem SGML (Standard
    Generalized Markup Language, standardizovani uopsteni jezik za oznacavanje) standarda sa svrhom opisa dokumenta koji se objavljuju na vebu.U pocetku je bio prilicno ogranicen sto se oznacavanja sadrzaja tice i pruzao je uglavnom elementarne stvari
    za oznacavanje i formatiranje teksta (paragrafi, naslovi, citati itd.). Kako je veb rastao tako je rasla i potreba za bogatijim sadrzajem te je u tom smeru razvijan i HTML standard. Tada su standardu dodate elementi za opis tabela, slika, slojeva,
    napredno formatiranje teksta itd.Svi HTML dokumenti bi trebalo da pocinju sa definicijom tipa dokumenta DTD, Document Type Definition koji pregledacu definise po kom standardu je dokument pisan.Ovaj kod govori pregledacu da je dokument pisan po strogom
    HTML 4.01 standardu. Ovaj konkretan standard iskljucuje koriscenje prezentacionih elemenata da bi se sto bolje odvojila prezentacija od sadrzaja.</p>

  <h2>CSS</h2>
  <p><img src="http://www.blackbirdsolutions.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/blog/css3-logo.png?itok=r8kt8WZA" alt="css logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;">CSS (engl. Cascading Style Sheets) je jezik formatiranja pomocu kog se definise
    izgled elemenata veb-stranice. Prvobitno, HTML je sluzio da definise kompletan izgled, strukturu i sadrzaj veb-stranice, ali je od verzije 4.0 HTML-a uveden CSS koji bi definisao konkretan izgled, dok je HTML ostao u funkciji definisanja strukture
    i sadrzaja.CSS je u odredjenoj formi postojao jos u zacecima SGML-a 1970-ih godina. Kako je HTML postajao komplikovaniji, davao je sve vise mogucnosti za definiciju izgleda elemenata, ali je istovremeno postajao necitljiviji i tezi za odrzavanje.
    Razliciti brauzeri su prikazivali dokumente na razlicite nacine, i postojala je potreba za doslednom tehnikom definisanja prikaza elemenata na stranici. Da bi se ovo postiglo, devet razlicitih metoda je predlozeno na zvanicnom forumu W3C-a. Od devet,
    dve metode su izabrane kao temelj onoga sto je kasnije postalo CSS: CHSS (engl. Cascading HTML Style Sheets) i SSP (engl. Stream-based Style Sheet Proposal). Prvo je Hakon Vium Li (koji je sada sef tehnicke sluzbe kompanije Opera) predlozio CHSS u
    oktobru 1994, jezik koji je imao dosta slicnosti sa danasnjim CSS-om. Bert Bos je radio na brauzeru po nazivu Argo, koji je imao sopstveni nacin definisanja stilova, SSP. Li i Bos su radili zajedno da bi osnovali CSS standard (slovo H je izbaceno
    iz skracenice CHSS jer se CSS mogao odnositi i na druge jezike pored HTML-a).</p>

</body>

<div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div id="p1"><b>Uradio: Marko Ribic Ia<b></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: One solution can be to change the body margin in percentage, and set the width of navbar to 100%-margin.

Comment: You have a **ton** of errors in your code. Don't use notepad. Use a code editor such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.3.3.html) or [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/). Also check your HTML for errors on the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Comment: Also, don't use your `body` tag for so much styling. If you need a container, just create a new `div` for that. You should also not use `margin` as a way to add padding.

Comment: Firstly please check your html code, it doesn't follow the standard. Opening and closing parenthesis aren't at the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly please check your html code, it doesn't follow the standards. Opening and closing parenthesis aren't at the right place.

I think the simple solution is to set left and right params on the navigacija item.

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

p {
  font-family: "Allerta Stencil";
  font-size: 25px;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: -5px;
  width: auto;
}

#navigacija {
  width: auto;
  right: 23px;
  left: 23px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #089DE3;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
}

.navitem {
  background: #089DE3;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navigacija a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  float: right;
}

.home:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.info:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #089DE3;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

#p1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="navigacija">
    <a href="Home.html">
      <div class="navitem home"><b>HOME</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem gallery"><b>GALLERY</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem contact"><b>CONTACT</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem info"><b>INFO</b></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1><b>HTML i CSS</b></h1>

  <h2>HTML</h2>
  <p><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" alt="html logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;"> HTML (engl. HyperText Markup Language, jezik za oznacavanje hiperteksta) je opisni jezik specijalno namenjen opisu veb stranica.
    Pomocu njega se jednostavno mogu odvojiti elementi kao sto su naslovi, paragrafi, citati i slicno. Pored toga, u HTML standard su ugradjeni elementi koji detaljnije opisuju sam dokument kao sto su kratak opis dokumenta, kljucne reci, podaci o autoru
    i slicno. Ovi podaci su opstepoznati kao meta podaci i jasno su odvojeni od sadrzaja dokumenta. Aktuelna verzija standarda je HTML 4.01, a sam standard odrzava Konzorcijum za Veb (W3C, World Wide Web Consortium).HTML je nastao uproscavanjem SGML (Standard
    Generalized Markup Language, standardizovani uopsteni jezik za oznacavanje) standarda sa svrhom opisa dokumenta koji se objavljuju na vebu.U pocetku je bio prilicno ogranicen sto se oznacavanja sadrzaja tice i pruzao je uglavnom elementarne stvari
    za oznacavanje i formatiranje teksta (paragrafi, naslovi, citati itd.). Kako je veb rastao tako je rasla i potreba za bogatijim sadrzajem te je u tom smeru razvijan i HTML standard. Tada su standardu dodate elementi za opis tabela, slika, slojeva,
    napredno formatiranje teksta itd.Svi HTML dokumenti bi trebalo da pocinju sa definicijom tipa dokumenta DTD, Document Type Definition koji pregledacu definise po kom standardu je dokument pisan.Ovaj kod govori pregledacu da je dokument pisan po strogom
    HTML 4.01 standardu. Ovaj konkretan standard iskljucuje koriscenje prezentacionih elemenata da bi se sto bolje odvojila prezentacija od sadrzaja.</p>

  <h2>CSS</h2>
  <p><img src="http://www.blackbirdsolutions.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/blog/css3-logo.png?itok=r8kt8WZA" alt="css logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;">CSS (engl. Cascading Style Sheets) je jezik formatiranja pomocu kog se definise
    izgled elemenata veb-stranice. Prvobitno, HTML je sluzio da definise kompletan izgled, strukturu i sadrzaj veb-stranice, ali je od verzije 4.0 HTML-a uveden CSS koji bi definisao konkretan izgled, dok je HTML ostao u funkciji definisanja strukture
    i sadrzaja.CSS je u odredjenoj formi postojao jos u zacecima SGML-a 1970-ih godina. Kako je HTML postajao komplikovaniji, davao je sve vise mogucnosti za definiciju izgleda elemenata, ali je istovremeno postajao necitljiviji i tezi za odrzavanje.
    Razliciti brauzeri su prikazivali dokumente na razlicite nacine, i postojala je potreba za doslednom tehnikom definisanja prikaza elemenata na stranici. Da bi se ovo postiglo, devet razlicitih metoda je predlozeno na zvanicnom forumu W3C-a. Od devet,
    dve metode su izabrane kao temelj onoga sto je kasnije postalo CSS: CHSS (engl. Cascading HTML Style Sheets) i SSP (engl. Stream-based Style Sheet Proposal). Prvo je Hakon Vium Li (koji je sada sef tehnicke sluzbe kompanije Opera) predlozio CHSS u
    oktobru 1994, jezik koji je imao dosta slicnosti sa danasnjim CSS-om. Bert Bos je radio na brauzeru po nazivu Argo, koji je imao sopstveni nacin definisanja stilova, SSP. Li i Bos su radili zajedno da bi osnovali CSS standard (slovo H je izbaceno
    iz skracenice CHSS jer se CSS mogao odnositi i na druge jezike pored HTML-a).</p>

</div>



<div class="footer">
  <div id="p1"><b>Uradio: Marko Ribic Ia</b></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

- Using `calc()`

You need to remove the margins from parent in your `100%` calculation,
so use `width: calc(100% - 50px);`

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

p {
  font-family: "Allerta Stencil";
  font-size: 25px;
}

#header {
  width: auto;
}

#navigacija {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #089DE3;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 35px;
  right:25px;
}

.navitem {
  background: #089DE3;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navigacija a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.home:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.info:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #089DE3;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

#p1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jockey+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta+Stencil" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="header">
  <div id="navigacija">
    <a href="Home.html">
      <div class="navitem home"><b>HOME</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem gallery"><b>GALLERY</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem contact"><b>CONTACT</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem info"><b>INFO</b></div>
    </a>
  </div>
 </div> 
  <h1><strong>HTML i CSS</strong></h1>

  <h2>HTML</h2>
  <p><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" alt="html logo"> HTML (engl. HyperText Markup Language, jezik za oznacavanje hiperteksta) je opisni jezik specijalno namenjen opisu veb stranica.
    Pomocu njega se jednostavno mogu odvojiti elementi kao sto su naslovi, paragrafi, citati i slicno. Pored toga, u HTML standard su ugradjeni elementi koji detaljnije opisuju sam dokument kao sto su kratak opis dokumenta, kljucne reci, podaci o autoru
    i slicno. Ovi podaci su opstepoznati kao meta podaci i jasno su odvojeni od sadrzaja dokumenta. Aktuelna verzija standarda je HTML 4.01, a sam standard odrzava Konzorcijum za Veb (W3C, World Wide Web Consortium).HTML je nastao uproscavanjem SGML (Standard
    Generalized Markup Language, standardizovani uopsteni jezik za oznacavanje) standarda sa svrhom opisa dokumenta koji se objavljuju na vebu.U pocetku je bio prilicno ogranicen sto se oznacavanja sadrzaja tice i pruzao je uglavnom elementarne stvari
    za oznacavanje i formatiranje teksta (paragrafi, naslovi, citati itd.). Kako je veb rastao tako je rasla i potreba za bogatijim sadrzajem te je u tom smeru razvijan i HTML standard. Tada su standardu dodate elementi za opis tabela, slika, slojeva,
    napredno formatiranje teksta itd.Svi HTML dokumenti bi trebalo da pocinju sa definicijom tipa dokumenta DTD, Document Type Definition koji pregledacu definise po kom standardu je dokument pisan.Ovaj kod govori pregledacu da je dokument pisan po strogom
    HTML 4.01 standardu. Ovaj konkretan standard iskljucuje koriscenje prezentacionih elemenata da bi se sto bolje odvojila prezentacija od sadrzaja.</p>

  <h2>CSS</h2>
  <p><img src="http://www.blackbirdsolutions.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/blog/css3-logo.png?itok=r8kt8WZA" alt="css logo">CSS (engl. Cascading Style Sheets) je jezik formatiranja pomocu kog se definise
    izgled elemenata veb-stranice. Prvobitno, HTML je sluzio da definise kompletan izgled, strukturu i sadrzaj veb-stranice, ali je od verzije 4.0 HTML-a uveden CSS koji bi definisao konkretan izgled, dok je HTML ostao u funkciji definisanja strukture
    i sadrzaja.CSS je u odredjenoj formi postojao jos u zacecima SGML-a 1970-ih godina. Kako je HTML postajao komplikovaniji, davao je sve vise mogucnosti za definiciju izgleda elemenata, ali je istovremeno postajao necitljiviji i tezi za odrzavanje.
    Razliciti brauzeri su prikazivali dokumente na razlicite nacine, i postojala je potreba za doslednom tehnikom definisanja prikaza elemenata na stranici. Da bi se ovo postiglo, devet razlicitih metoda je predlozeno na zvanicnom forumu W3C-a. Od devet,
    dve metode su izabrane kao temelj onoga sto je kasnije postalo CSS: CHSS (engl. Cascading HTML Style Sheets) i SSP (engl. Stream-based Style Sheet Proposal). Prvo je Hakon Vium Li (koji je sada sef tehnicke sluzbe kompanije Opera) predlozio CHSS u
    oktobru 1994, jezik koji je imao dosta slicnosti sa danasnjim CSS-om. Bert Bos je radio na brauzeru po nazivu Argo, koji je imao sopstveni nacin definisanja stilova, SSP. Li i Bos su radili zajedno da bi osnovali CSS standard (slovo H je izbaceno
    iz skracenice CHSS jer se CSS mogao odnositi i na druge jezike pored HTML-a).</p>


  <div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div id="p1"><strong>Uradio: Marko Ribic Ia</strong></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

- using `position`

use `left/right` to adjust the position where it starts and ends

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

p {
  font-family: "Allerta Stencil";
  font-size: 25px;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: auto;
}

#navigacija {
  width: calc(100% - 45px);
  padding: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #089DE3;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 35px
}

.navitem {
  background: #089DE3;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navigacija a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

.home:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.info:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #089DE3;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

#p1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jockey+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta+Stencil" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="header">
  <div id="navigacija">
    <a href="Home.html">
      <div class="navitem home"><b>HOME</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem gallery"><b>GALLERY</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem contact"><b>CONTACT</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem info"><b>INFO</b></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<h1><strong>HTML i CSS</strong></h1>

<h2>HTML</h2>
<p><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" alt="html logo"> HTML (engl. HyperText Markup Language, jezik za oznacavanje hiperteksta) je opisni jezik specijalno namenjen opisu veb stranica. Pomocu
  njega se jednostavno mogu odvojiti elementi kao sto su naslovi, paragrafi, citati i slicno. Pored toga, u HTML standard su ugradjeni elementi koji detaljnije opisuju sam dokument kao sto su kratak opis dokumenta, kljucne reci, podaci o autoru i slicno.
  Ovi podaci su opstepoznati kao meta podaci i jasno su odvojeni od sadrzaja dokumenta. Aktuelna verzija standarda je HTML 4.01, a sam standard odrzava Konzorcijum za Veb (W3C, World Wide Web Consortium).HTML je nastao uproscavanjem SGML (Standard Generalized
  Markup Language, standardizovani uopsteni jezik za oznacavanje) standarda sa svrhom opisa dokumenta koji se objavljuju na vebu.U pocetku je bio prilicno ogranicen sto se oznacavanja sadrzaja tice i pruzao je uglavnom elementarne stvari za oznacavanje
  i formatiranje teksta (paragrafi, naslovi, citati itd.). Kako je veb rastao tako je rasla i potreba za bogatijim sadrzajem te je u tom smeru razvijan i HTML standard. Tada su standardu dodate elementi za opis tabela, slika, slojeva, napredno formatiranje
  teksta itd.Svi HTML dokumenti bi trebalo da pocinju sa definicijom tipa dokumenta DTD, Document Type Definition koji pregledacu definise po kom standardu je dokument pisan.Ovaj kod govori pregledacu da je dokument pisan po strogom HTML 4.01 standardu.
  Ovaj konkretan standard iskljucuje koriscenje prezentacionih elemenata da bi se sto bolje odvojila prezentacija od sadrzaja.</p>

<h2>CSS</h2>
<p><img src="http://www.blackbirdsolutions.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/blog/css3-logo.png?itok=r8kt8WZA" alt="css logo">CSS (engl. Cascading Style Sheets) je jezik formatiranja pomocu kog se definise
  izgled elemenata veb-stranice. Prvobitno, HTML je sluzio da definise kompletan izgled, strukturu i sadrzaj veb-stranice, ali je od verzije 4.0 HTML-a uveden CSS koji bi definisao konkretan izgled, dok je HTML ostao u funkciji definisanja strukture i
  sadrzaja.CSS je u odredjenoj formi postojao jos u zacecima SGML-a 1970-ih godina. Kako je HTML postajao komplikovaniji, davao je sve vise mogucnosti za definiciju izgleda elemenata, ali je istovremeno postajao necitljiviji i tezi za odrzavanje. Razliciti
  brauzeri su prikazivali dokumente na razlicite nacine, i postojala je potreba za doslednom tehnikom definisanja prikaza elemenata na stranici. Da bi se ovo postiglo, devet razlicitih metoda je predlozeno na zvanicnom forumu W3C-a. Od devet, dve metode
  su izabrane kao temelj onoga sto je kasnije postalo CSS: CHSS (engl. Cascading HTML Style Sheets) i SSP (engl. Stream-based Style Sheet Proposal). Prvo je Hakon Vium Li (koji je sada sef tehnicke sluzbe kompanije Opera) predlozio CHSS u oktobru 1994,
  jezik koji je imao dosta slicnosti sa danasnjim CSS-om. Bert Bos je radio na brauzeru po nazivu Argo, koji je imao sopstveni nacin definisanja stilova, SSP. Li i Bos su radili zajedno da bi osnovali CSS standard (slovo H je izbaceno iz skracenice CHSS
  jer se CSS mogao odnositi i na druge jezike pored HTML-a).</p>


<div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div id="p1"><strong>Uradio: Marko Ribic Ia</strong></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Note:

you have a lot of errors in your code, fix them and you will have what you want.

- unclosed tags
- there is no negative `padding`

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here the fix...

```
    #navigacija {
      width: auto;

      /* HERE THE FIX*/
      left: 20px; 
      right: 20px; 

      padding: 0px;
      height: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: right;
      background-color: #089DE3;
      z-index: 9999;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 25px;
      position: fixed;
    }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
     box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  }
  
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Jockey One";
    color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  h2 {
   font-family: "Jockey One";
   font-size: 50px;
   color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  }
  
  p {
   font-family: "Allerta Stencil";
   font-size: 25px;
  }
  
  #header {
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: -5px;
  width: auto;
  }

  
  
  #navigacija {
      width: auto;
      
      /* HERE THE FIX*/
      left: 20px; 
      right: 20px; 
    
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #089DE3;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: fixed;
  }
  
  .navitem {
    background: #089DE3;
    color: white;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Fjalla One";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  #navigacija a {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  }
  
  img {
   float:right;
  
  }
  
  
  .home:hover {
    background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .gallery:hover {
    background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .contact:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #00C5CD;
  }
  .info:hover {
   
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
  }

  .footer {
  background-color: #089DE3;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  }
 
  #p1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One"; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML i CSS</title>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jockey+One" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta+Stencil" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">

 



  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="navigacija">
        <a href="Home.html">
          <div class="navitem home"><b>HOME</b></div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="navitem gallery"><b>GALLERY</b></div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="navitem contact"><b>CONTACT</b></div>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="navitem info"><b>INFO</b></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h1><b>HTML i CSS</b></h1>
 
 <h2>HTML</h2>
 <p><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" alt="html logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;"> HTML (engl. HyperText Markup Language, jezik za oznacavanje hiperteksta) je opisni jezik specijalno namenjen opisu veb stranica. Pomocu njega se jednostavno mogu odvojiti elementi kao sto su naslovi, paragrafi, citati i slicno. Pored toga, u HTML standard su ugradjeni elementi koji detaljnije opisuju sam dokument kao sto su kratak opis dokumenta, kljucne reci, podaci o autoru i slicno. Ovi podaci su opstepoznati kao meta podaci i jasno su odvojeni od sadrzaja dokumenta.

Aktuelna verzija standarda je HTML 4.01, a sam standard odrzava Konzorcijum za Veb (W3C, World Wide Web Consortium).HTML je nastao uproscavanjem SGML (Standard Generalized Markup Language, standardizovani uopsteni jezik za oznacavanje) standarda sa svrhom opisa dokumenta koji se objavljuju na vebu.U pocetku je bio prilicno ogranicen sto se oznacavanja sadrzaja tice i pruzao je uglavnom elementarne stvari za oznacavanje i formatiranje teksta (paragrafi, naslovi, citati itd.). Kako je veb rastao tako je rasla i potreba za bogatijim sadrzajem te je u tom smeru razvijan i HTML standard. Tada su standardu dodate elementi za opis tabela, slika, slojeva, napredno formatiranje teksta itd.Svi HTML dokumenti bi trebalo da pocinju sa definicijom tipa dokumenta DTD, Document Type Definition koji pregledacu definise po kom standardu je dokument pisan.Ovaj kod govori pregledacu da je dokument pisan po strogom HTML 4.01 standardu. Ovaj konkretan standard iskljucuje koriscenje prezentacionih elemenata da bi se sto bolje odvojila prezentacija od sadrzaja.</p>

 <h2>CSS</h2>
 <p><img src="http://www.blackbirdsolutions.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/blog/css3-logo.png?itok=r8kt8WZA" alt="css logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;">CSS (engl. Cascading Style Sheets) je jezik formatiranja pomocu kog se definise izgled elemenata veb-stranice.

Prvobitno, HTML je sluzio da definise kompletan izgled, strukturu i sadrzaj veb-stranice, ali je od verzije 4.0 HTML-a uveden CSS koji bi definisao konkretan izgled, dok je HTML ostao u funkciji definisanja strukture i sadrzaja.CSS je u odredjenoj formi postojao jos u zacecima SGML-a 1970-ih godina.

Kako je HTML postajao komplikovaniji, davao je sve vise mogucnosti za definiciju izgleda elemenata, ali je istovremeno postajao necitljiviji i tezi za odrzavanje. Razliciti brauzeri su prikazivali dokumente na razlicite nacine, i postojala je potreba za doslednom tehnikom definisanja prikaza elemenata na stranici.

Da bi se ovo postiglo, devet razlicitih metoda je predlozeno na zvanicnom forumu W3C-a. Od devet, dve metode su izabrane kao temelj onoga sto je kasnije postalo CSS: CHSS (engl. Cascading HTML Style Sheets) i SSP (engl. Stream-based Style Sheet Proposal). Prvo je Hakon Vium Li (koji je sada sef tehnicke sluzbe kompanije Opera) predlozio CHSS u oktobru 1994, jezik koji je imao dosta slicnosti sa danasnjim CSS-om. Bert Bos je radio na brauzeru po nazivu Argo, koji je imao sopstveni nacin definisanja stilova, SSP. Li i Bos su radili zajedno da bi osnovali CSS standard (slovo H je izbaceno iz skracenice CHSS jer se CSS mogao odnositi i na druge jezike pored HTML-a).</p>
 
</body>

<div>
<div class="footer">
 <div id="p1"><b>Uradio: Marko Ribic Ia<b></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Jockey One";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

p {
  font-family: "Allerta Stencil";
  font-size: 25px;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: -5px;
  width: auto;
}

#navigacija {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #089DE3;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}

.navitem {
  background: #089DE3;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navigacija a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  float: right;
}

.home:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.info:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #089DE3;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

#p1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="navigacija">
    <a href="Home.html">
      <div class="navitem home"><b>HOME</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem gallery"><b>GALLERY</b></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="navitem contact"><b>CONTACT</b></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="navitem info"><b>INFO</b></div>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>

<h1><b>HTML i CSS</b></h1>

<h2>HTML</h2>
<p><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" alt="html logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;"> HTML (engl. HyperText Markup Language, jezik za oznacavanje hiperteksta) je opisni jezik specijalno namenjen opisu veb stranica. Pomocu
  njega se jednostavno mogu odvojiti elementi kao sto su naslovi, paragrafi, citati i slicno. Pored toga, u HTML standard su ugradjeni elementi koji detaljnije opisuju sam dokument kao sto su kratak opis dokumenta, kljucne reci, podaci o autoru i slicno.
  Ovi podaci su opstepoznati kao meta podaci i jasno su odvojeni od sadrzaja dokumenta. Aktuelna verzija standarda je HTML 4.01, a sam standard odrzava Konzorcijum za Veb (W3C, World Wide Web Consortium).HTML je nastao uproscavanjem SGML (Standard Generalized
  Markup Language, standardizovani uopsteni jezik za oznacavanje) standarda sa svrhom opisa dokumenta koji se objavljuju na vebu.U pocetku je bio prilicno ogranicen sto se oznacavanja sadrzaja tice i pruzao je uglavnom elementarne stvari za oznacavanje
  i formatiranje teksta (paragrafi, naslovi, citati itd.). Kako je veb rastao tako je rasla i potreba za bogatijim sadrzajem te je u tom smeru razvijan i HTML standard. Tada su standardu dodate elementi za opis tabela, slika, slojeva, napredno formatiranje
  teksta itd.Svi HTML dokumenti bi trebalo da pocinju sa definicijom tipa dokumenta DTD, Document Type Definition koji pregledacu definise po kom standardu je dokument pisan.Ovaj kod govori pregledacu da je dokument pisan po strogom HTML 4.01 standardu.
  Ovaj konkretan standard iskljucuje koriscenje prezentacionih elemenata da bi se sto bolje odvojila prezentacija od sadrzaja.</p>

<h2>CSS</h2>
<p><img src="http://www.blackbirdsolutions.com.au/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/blog/css3-logo.png?itok=r8kt8WZA" alt="css logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;">CSS (engl. Cascading Style Sheets) je jezik formatiranja pomocu kog se definise
  izgled elemenata veb-stranice. Prvobitno, HTML je sluzio da definise kompletan izgled, strukturu i sadrzaj veb-stranice, ali je od verzije 4.0 HTML-a uveden CSS koji bi definisao konkretan izgled, dok je HTML ostao u funkciji definisanja strukture i
  sadrzaja.CSS je u odredjenoj formi postojao jos u zacecima SGML-a 1970-ih godina. Kako je HTML postajao komplikovaniji, davao je sve vise mogucnosti za definiciju izgleda elemenata, ali je istovremeno postajao necitljiviji i tezi za odrzavanje. Razliciti
  brauzeri su prikazivali dokumente na razlicite nacine, i postojala je potreba za doslednom tehnikom definisanja prikaza elemenata na stranici. Da bi se ovo postiglo, devet razlicitih metoda je predlozeno na zvanicnom forumu W3C-a. Od devet, dve metode
  su izabrane kao temelj onoga sto je kasnije postalo CSS: CHSS (engl. Cascading HTML Style Sheets) i SSP (engl. Stream-based Style Sheet Proposal). Prvo je Hakon Vium Li (koji je sada sef tehnicke sluzbe kompanije Opera) predlozio CHSS u oktobru 1994,
  jezik koji je imao dosta slicnosti sa danasnjim CSS-om. Bert Bos je radio na brauzeru po nazivu Argo, koji je imao sopstveni nacin definisanja stilova, SSP. Li i Bos su radili zajedno da bi osnovali CSS standard (slovo H je izbaceno iz skracenice CHSS
  jer se CSS mogao odnositi i na druge jezike pored HTML-a).</p>


<div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div id="p1"><b>Uradio: Marko Ribic Ia<b></div>
</div>
```